# the best way to learn emacs

Tags: learning

I'm dealing with learning emacs from a while, but I've still not find a god solution.
I find the docs on the web site not well structured. There for sure I can find any explication of all command, but I'm looking for somethings that explain me gradualy how emacs works (because it is somethings very different from any other editor)

Can someone show me somethings?

Comment: Have you done the tutorial yet? It's a bit basic and omits many modern features, but it's a start. Beyond that, what kind of things do you do? E.g. a tutorial for editing Java code and a tutorial for editing LaTeX would be pretty different.

Comment: Questions seeking "the best way" encourage opinion-based answers. A discussion site is more appropriate for such questions. This site is more for specific how-to or what-is questions.

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SiteMap#LearningEmacs

Comment: Related question https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/342/

Comment: I would use it mainly (and, of course primarely)to edit .rst file